# Change a cell value permanently in Excel

Tags: excel

I prepared an Excel worksheet to monitor my trades on Binance crypto market. I created a simple formula to  make one cell's value (A12 for example) change to "done" when the coin's value is equal to sell price. (pretty easy). However, this changes when the coin's price becomes less than sell price!

Is there any way to make the word "done" permeant when the condition is met?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Use VBA perhaps: `Worksheet_Change` or `Worksheet_Calculate` event.

Comment: I assume your formula in A12 is referencing a cell which contains the coin's value. I assume that that cell also contains a formula? If so, I'd use a Worksheet_Change event handler to grab that cell's value and then reassign it back to the cell. Thus fixing the value in A12.

Answer (score 0):

You could experiment with circular references. Check the "enable iterative calculation" option in the formula tab of the Excel options under the File menu. Then, as proof of concept, in `A12` enter the formula:

```
=IF(A12="done","done",IF(A11>5,"done","undone"))
```

This will switch to "done" the first time the value exceeds 5 but won't switch back to "undone" if the value later drops below.

On the other hand, circular references make the worksheet harder to reason about. A VBA solution will probably be more robust.

Comment: Thank you pal. Actually I don't have enough knowledge about VBA. If you could help me with a simple code I would be very grateful to you.